# Sorting some set of number

Tags: sorting

Let $U=\{1,2,3\cdots m-1\}$ and some $n$ keys from $U$. Is it possible to sort these $n$ keys in $O(n \log \log n)$ time using $O(n)$ space?

Model of computation is RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is studied by Yijie Han in his paper [1].

There's also a relevant question on *cstheory*: [Han's $O(n\log\log n)$ time, linear space, integer sorting algorithm](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/hans-on-log-log-n-time-linear-space-integer-sorting-algorithm).

---

[1] [Han, Y. (2002, May). Deterministic sorting in O (n log log n) time and linear space. In *Proceedings of the thiry-fourth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing* (pp. 602-608). ACM.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019667740300155X)

Comment: It seems the paper uses $\Theta(n+m)$ spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to clarify your question. It is certainly not possible as written, because the running time and space usage should depend on $m$, not just on $n$.

In particular, if $m$ is very large, then $n$ numbers may take a large amount of space to write out in the first place, which immediately lower bounds the running time.

Comment: Is it possible to do in $O(n \log \log n)$ space wth the time mentioned in the question.

Comment: @old You sort a list, not a set. A set is not ordered. It is not clear what you want to sort.

Comment: (1) In the usual RAM model, every memory cell holds a machine word of length $O(\log N)$ bits, where $N$ is the length of the input in bits, and operations on a single machine word take $O(1)$ time. In this case, assuming the standard encoding, $N = n\log m$, and so we are allowed constant time operations on words of length $O(\log n + \log \log m)$ bits. (2) Space consumption doesn't include the input. (3) OP might have meant to use $N$ rather than $n$ in their time and space requirements.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks for your comment, I only have a vague understanding of the RAM model so I maybe should not have answered. I upvoted your comment and your own answer for visibility.

Comment: That's OK, nobody understands the RAM model...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to sort them [in $O(n)$ time using $O(1)$ extra space](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~muthu/soradix.pdf). So yes.

Comment: This is for words of size $O(\log n)$, that is, when $m$ is polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Yes, that's the word RAM model.